# Организация множества записей в БД

Tags: mysql, база-данных

У нас есть бд на несколько миллионов записей почты.

```
mail1@gmail.com
mail2@yahoo.com
mail3@yandex.ru
mail@aol.com
```

В дальнейшем у нас будут запросы, к которым будут относится разные адреса:

```
электрочайник:
mail1@gmail.com 
mail3@yandex.ru 

пепси:
mail2@yahoo.com 
mail3@yandex.ru 

хлеб:
mail@aol.com
```

Получается что одному запросу может соответствовать очень много адресов, иногда даже вся база. Как в таком случае хранить запросы и соответствующие им адреса, ведь тогда таблица получится огромная? Спасибо.

Comment: Я не сказать что силен в этом, но сделал бы так: одна таблица где хранится список всех адресов, а в другой столбец наименование товара и столбец emails, текстом через запятую или ;

Comment: Это вроде нарушает все правила построения свзяей между таблицами.

Comment: а если в первой id email, а во второй товар emails, и в нем список id тех эмайлов что соответствуют

Comment: Так тоже нельзя

Comment: Возможно вам поможет создание связи многие когда многим через промежуточную таблицу вида таблица1.Ид и таблица2.Ид

Comment: Так а размер таблицы какой тогда будет? Он же будет огромным. Какой по скорости тогда будет выборка из нее

Answer (score 0):

Наиболее оптимальное решение между требованиями (скорость выборки-обьем БД) просто добавить в таблицу столбец с наименованием запроса  [id | e-mail | запрос]

Если есть такая возможнось можно сделать id запроса [id | e-mail | id запроca]
 сравнивание по INT будет происходить быстрее нежели слов